# Try to Select jsonl data column in another columns with .loc but got KeyError even though the key exists

Tags: python, pandas, jsonlines

this is my data structure in jsonl

```
"content": "Not yall gassing up a gay boy with no rhythm", "place": {"_type": "snscrape.modules.twitter.Place", "fullName": "Manhattan, NY", "name": "Manhattan", "type": "city", "country": "United States", "countryCode": "US"}
```

i try to select countryCode from place column with this code

```
country_df = test_df.loc[test_df['place'].notnull(), ['content', 'place']]
countrycode_df = country_df["place"].loc["countryCode"]
```

but it gave me this error

KeyError: 'countryCode'

how do i fix this?

I had try this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733588/how-to-read-this-column-of-jsonl-data-that-mayb-null-in-json-file-using-pandas-r/67733679?noredirect=1#comment119730209_67733679) but it doesnt fit my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it with `str`:

```
country_df['place'].str['countryCode']
```

Output:

```
0    US
Name: place, dtype: object
```

Comment: i was able to get the same result but i cant use `.groupby("countryCode").size()` without this error " KeyError: 'countryCode' " anyway to solve this?

Comment: Sure, you can do `df.groupby(df['place'].str['countryCode']).size()` (or just `df['place'].str['countryCode'].value_counts()` if you only want to know how many records with each `countryCode` you have)

Comment: Or you can use `json_normalize` to convert `place` to a DataFrame and then you can work with `countryCode` as a column: `pd.json_normalize(df['place'])`

Comment: sry if this out of topic how do i merge the result with my content column?

Comment: Something like `pd.json_normalize(df.to_dict(orient='records'))` to normalize all columns

Comment: I had try to normalize my data like this `countrycode_df = pd.json_normalize(data=country_df)` but i got this error instead "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values' "

Comment: @someoneudon'tknow You need `.to_dict(orient='records')`

Answer (score 0):

Since "place" is basically a `dict` (a nested dict), you can access it like the higher level `dict`

```
country = {"content": "Not yall gassing up a gay boy with no rhythm", "place": {"_type": "snscrape.modules.twitter.Place", "fullName": "Manhattan, NY", "name": "Manhattan", "type": "city", "country": "United States", "countryCode": "US"}}
country["place"]["countryCode"]
```

output:

```
'US'
```

However, it might be better for your purpose to use  pandas `json_normalize()`:

```
country_df = pd.json_normalize(data = country)

print(country_df )
```

output:

| content | place._type | place.fullName | place.name | place.type | place.country | place.countryCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Not yall gassing up a gay boy with no rhythm | snscrape.modules.twitter.Place | Manhattan, NY | Manhattan | city | United States | US |

Comment: is it the best approach to just normalize all my data before use `.groupby`?

Comment: I would suggest so... `.groupby()` is a DataFrame function and with `json_normalize()` you convert the json to a DataFrame

Comment: I had try to normalize my data like this `countrycode_df = pd.json_normalize(data=country_df)` but i got this error instead "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values' "

Comment: had solve it need to add `df.to_dict(orient='records')`

Comment: the data provided to the json_normalize needs to be a json. Sound like your data is already partially a DataFrame

Comment: Mayb the reason my data got processed once with this code `country_df = test_df.loc[test_df['place'].notnull(), ['content', 'place']]` which for some reason only cause it to partially dataframe

Comment: indeed, I adjusted my answer to make the flow more clear